# Trilateration using 4 fixed points

Tags: math, gps, trilateration

I am trying to figure out a problem where you pretend you're a GPS unit at an unknown target location (latitude and longitude co-ordinates). I was given the data of 4 satellites (latitude and longitude co-ordinate pairs and for each pair a distance in kilometers to the target location and Delta Time). Does anyone know how to calculate the co-ordinates of the target location?  I tried doing research but the math involved is way beyond me. Thanking you in advance for any help.

Here is the data:

```
Satellite 1
LAT  24.54653
LONG  -81.79745
HEIGHT (m)  20183000
DELTATIME (s)  0.070808428

Satellite 2
LAT  63.75088
LONG  -68.56082
HEIGHT (m)  20183000
DELTATIME (s)  0.069105305

Satellite 3
LAT  53.90460
LONG  -166.52657
HEIGHT (m)  20183000
DELTATIME (s)  0.073341842

Satellite 4
LAT  43.41038
LONG  -65.61692
HEIGHT (m)  20183000
DELTATIME (s)  0.069680227
```

Comment: Where do you need help? My first guess at the first step is that you should translate the lat/long/height values of the satellites into x/y/z coordinates, have you got that far?

Comment: I converted the lat/long/height values into x/y/z  That's as far as I can get.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your sattelite data from their [geographic coordinate system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system) (using lat/long/height) to x/y/z, then solve the [navigation equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System#Navigation_equations). If you like, convert the result back to geographic coordinates. If you want to the result to be reasonably accurate, you should figure out the [geodetic datum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodetic_datum) underlying your geographic coordinate system.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I took a look at the equations but that is way beyond my comprehension.  I might have to find someone that can solve that for me.